# How to fix Compile path issue in M1

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, compiler-warnings, vscode-debugger

When I run C++ in VScode it shows:

```
Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin".  Using "/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11" instead.
[2/10/2022, 12:58:19 AM] Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin".  Using "/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11" instead.
```

Further, when I try to run C++ code it shows:

```
Unable to find executable for '/Users/dharshanm/Documents/VS Studio codes/build/Debug/outDebug'
```

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward. The first path doesn't exist, or it can't find a compiler there. So it's using your homebrew installation instead. Although that path for a brew installation doesn't look right. The easiest thing to do on a Mac is to install the Xcode CLT and let VS Code just use it, which it generally will out of the box. FWIW, my g++ is located at `/usr/bin/g++`. Same with clang++. My brew installation of LLVM is located at `/usr/local/opt/llvm`. You're either missing tools or misconfigured the extension.

Comment: I believe MS offers guides for getting set up; just follow that.

Comment: I did just learn that brew uses a different path on ARM vs Intel. https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/ I am on an Intel Mac. It now has me wondering if the path is really that different for the system compiler as well.